# How to say "unless...?" in the context of "but what if"

Tags: phrase-requests

In the context of the phrase ["Just kidding... unless...?"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/just-kidding-unless), how would the word "unless" be translated? Here, "unless" has sort of a connotation of "what if...?" as well as "unless you want to?"

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use
冗談でした。。。けど。。。もしか。。。